# Use cookie with Httpclient on Android

Tags: java, android, cookies, httpclient

I'm trying to get a session cookies when i authenticate my user but i don't understand witch way is the best with Httpclient.

```
public void postData() {
// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.yoursite.com/script.php");
try {
    // Add your data
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringdata", "AndDev is Cool!"));
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

    // Execute HTTP Post Request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146861/android-httpclient-persistent-cookies)

Comment: yes, but this exemple is for put a cookie , not for get . I'm wrong ?

Comment: Is for creating a `HttpContext`, once you've set the context you can add as well as retrieve the cookies from it.